# mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a list of 20 teams, and 360 fixtures. this forms 2 table:

#### teams

- id
- name

#### fixtures

- id
- hometeam
- homescore
- awayteam
- awayscore
- datetime

Basically I want to try and do a calculation against each team and store it in the database. It will use all the data from the fixtures table and create the following:

**possible stored procedure**

teamname, number of home wins from last 5 home fixtures, number of draws from last 5 home fixtures, number of draws from last 5 away fixtures, number of away wins from last 5 away fixtures.

I want to use this data to use as a current form for each team, and as this data will be used in a lot of places throughout my site I really need to work out the best way of doing this.

Comment: Stored procedures are the enemy of maintainability and performance. Avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one query, you need two joins:

```
SELECT t.name,
    SUM(IF(f_h.homescore > f_h.awayscore, 1, 0)) AS HomeWins,
    SUM(IF(f_h.homescore = f_h.awayscore, 1, 0)) AS HomeDraws,
    SUM(IF(f_a.awayscore > f_a.homescore, 1, 0)) AS AwayWins,
    SUM(IF(f_a.awayscore = f_a.homescore, 1, 0)) AS AwayDraws 
FROM team t 
LEFT JOIN fixtures f_h ON f_h.hometeam = t.id AND f_h.id IN (
    SELECT id    
    FROM fixtures
    WHERE hometeam = t.id
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 5)
LEFT JOIN fixtures f_a ON f_a.awayteam = t.id AND f_a.id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM fixtures
    WHERE awayteam = t.id
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 5)
GROUP BY t.name
```

The subselect is needed to get only the last 5 fixtures.

Comment: Im getting an error on line 2 for this, and I cant seem to work out exactly what you have done. any ideas?

Comment: sorry, forgot parentheses from IF statements. Edited the query, try it now

Comment: thanks very much for your help on this :)

also im using mysql 5.0.92 and I dont think the IN statement works, I dont suppose you know an alternative to this by anychance?

Comment: Yes, IN statement has to work at MySQL 5.0.x: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: thanks again for your help. I get an error sayin:

this version of mysql doesnt yet support LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery. I assumed it was because IN wasnt supported :(

Comment: It turned out I cant use LIMIT in a subquery. Is there an alternative?